# My bmi calculator is running backwards

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Bmi calculator that I am writing for school is producing my output backwards, it first calls for user information and than for name information. Please help, i need it to be the other way around.

```
user = str
end = False

def bmi_intro():
    print("BMI Calculator")
    while end == False:


        user = input("Enter students name or '0' to quit: ")
        if user == "0":
            print("end of report!")
        else:
            def userName(str):
                user = str
            print("Lets gather your information,", user)
            break

    get_height = float(input("Please enter your height in inches: "))
    get_weight = float(input("Please enter your weight: "))
    body_mass_index = (get_weight * 703) / (get_height ** 2)
    print ("Your bmi is: ", body_mass_index)

def main():
  get_height = 0.0
  get_weight = 0.0
  body_mass_index = 0.0
bmi_intro()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: You need to remove the `break` and indent the lines related to the user's weight and height so that it is inside the `else`.  You also need to set the value of `end`.  See my answer below.

Comment: Python isn't a statically typed language, meaning you can't/don't need to define a variable's type before assignment. So `user = str` does nothing in your case.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues in your code:

- You have not set the value of `end`
- You have not indented correctly
- The `main` function is redundant in this case

It should be as follows:

```
def bmi_intro():
  end = False

  print("BMI Calculator")

  while end == False:

      user = input("Enter student's name or '0' to quit: ")
      if user == "0":
          print("end of report!")
          end = True
      else:
          print("Lets gather your information,", user)

          get_height = float(input("Please enter your height in inches: "))
          get_weight = float(input("Please enter your weight: "))
          body_mass_index = (get_weight * 703) / (get_height ** 2)

          print ("Your bmi is:", body_mass_index)

bmi_intro()
```

**Additional suggestions**

You may like to indicate the unit of measurement in your question for the weight i.e.:

```
get_weight = float(input("Please enter your weight in pounds (lbs): "))
```

A function is not required unless you plan on extending this code and/or adding additional functions.  You could do away with the function definition and the function call if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Correction of indentation and removing `break` statement can solve your problem (I have tried to edit your code as less as possible, I think it will be helpful to you to understand the code):

```
user = str
end = False

def bmi_intro():
        print("BMI Calculator")
        while end == False:


        user = input("Enter students name or '0' to quit: ")
        if user == "0":
            print("end of report!")
            break
        else:
            def userName(str):
                user = str
            print("Lets gather your information,", user)


            get_height = float(input("Please enter your height in inches: "))
            get_weight = float(input("Please enter your weight: "))
            body_mass_index = (get_weight * 703) / (get_height ** 2)
            print ("Your bmi is: ", body_mass_index)

def main():
  get_height = 0.0
  get_weight = 0.0
  body_mass_index = 0.0
bmi_intro()
```